# How to set fuse.js options

Tags: javascript, fuzzy-search, fuse.js

```js
const JSON = [
  {
    "name": "01,02"
  },
  {
    "name": "01"
  },
  {
    "name": "05"
  },
  {
    "name": "06,09"
  },
  {
    "name": "04,05"
  },
  {
    "name": "02,03"
  },
  {
    "name": "02,04,05"
  },
  {
    "name": "01,02"
  },
  {
    "name": "01,03"
  }
]


function foo (str) {
  const options = {
    keys: ['name'],
    threshold: 0,
    location: 0,
    distance: 100,
    minMatchCharLength: str.length
  }
  const _fuse = new Fuse(JSON, options)
  console.log(_fuse.search(str))
}

foo('03')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuse.js/3.2.1/fuse.min.js"></script>
```

I am trying to use `fuse.js` for filtering. I am unsure of how to use the options. If I search with `03` I am not returning any results. I have tried changing the location and threshold but not completely understanding it. I set the `minMatchCharLength` to the length of the query string thinking that would prevent a query of `01` from returning items that only contain a `0`. Is that correct?

Comment: try to change `"name"`to `name`, also try to read the various explanations under each option. you can also try in the demo
http://fusejs.io/

Comment: paste your json and try to 'play'

Comment: threshold  : At what point does the match algorithm give up. A threshold of 0.0 requires a perfect match (of both letters and location), a threshold of 1.0 would match anything.

Comment: example : https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/qw1dzL83/2/

Comment: @Leo can you put in answer? Thanks

Comment: now I'm not at the PC, as soon as I can create the answer, maybe giving further explanations ;)

Comment: done :) I hope I have helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine already.
You set threshold to `0` which means

```
fuse requires a perfct match (of both letters and location)
```

And there is no `name` property which is exactly `03`.

So if you fiddle just with threshold and set it to `0.2` for example - you will get some results from search:

```
[{name: "02,03"}, {name: "01,03"}]
```

Comment: Agreed but also, if you don't care about string location, you may set distance to a very high number (99999999). This would allow you have a lower threshold (0.01) very focused on string characters and not on location.

Answer (score 0):

With `threshold: 0`, your name must exactly match both location and content, so that means search for "03" will only return items starting with "03".

If you want to keep the exact matching, but want to allow your search string to be anywhere within the name, [since Fuse 6.2.0](https://github.com/krisk/Fuse/releases/tag/v6.2.0) you can now use the [ignoreLocation](https://fusejs.io/api/options.html#ignorelocation) parameter. As per the docs:

> When true, search will ignore location and distance, so it won't matter where in the string the pattern appears.

So your example params would look like:

```js
// ...  
const options = {
    keys: ['name'],
    threshold: 0,
    ignoreLocation: true,
    location: 0,
    distance: 100,
    minMatchCharLength: str.length
}
// ...
```

This is a better alternative to previous approaches, where you had to use high `distance` and low but non-zero `threshold`

Answer (score -1):

try to change `"name"` to `name`:

```
const JSON =  [
  {
    name: "01,02"
  },
  {
    name: "01"
  },
  {
    name: "05"
  },
  {
    name: "06,09"
  },
  {
    name: "04,05"
  },
  {
    name: "02,03"
  },
  {
    name: "02,04,05"
  },
  {
    name: "01,02"
  },
  {
    name: "01,03"
  }
];
```

Here you can find a demo that allows you to 'play' with the configurations.
You can paste your json and try to get different results:
[Link](http://fusejs.io/)

For more information about the configuration, you can refer to step 2 of the previous link, which explains all the options.
Eg: **threshold** : At what point does the match algorithm give up. A threshold of 0.0 requires a perfect match (of both letters and location), a threshold of 1.0 would match anything

Here a demo with your example : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/qw1dzL83/2/)